# Fragment communicating between fragment using interface failed, nullpointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments

Trying to Communicating FragmentA to FragmentB, doing is taking numeric value from fragmentA adding them and displaying  result in fragmentB using interface, but I got nullpointerException, I have look many times in the code but seems everything is fine but getting nullpointerException showing line 34 in  FragmentA

```
    listener.setResult(result+" ");
```

Here's My FragmentA

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment{
MyFragmentInterface listener;
Button buton;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a,container,false);
    final EditText editText= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text1);
    final EditText editText2= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text2);
    buton= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    buton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                    int num1=Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
                    int num2=Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());
                    int result=num1+num2;
            listener.setResult(result+" ");
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
  listener= (MyFragmentInterface) context;
    super.onAttach(context);
}
}
```

Here's my fragment_a.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/edit_text1"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="30sp"/>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:id="@+id/edit_text2"
    android:textSize="30sp"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Calculate"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:background="@null"
    android:textAllCaps="false"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

FragmentB.java

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
TextView textView;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    textView= (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textview);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b,container,false);
}
public void putresult(String r){
    textView.setText(r);
}
}
```

fragment_b.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="30sp"
android:id="@+id/textview"
android:text="Text will appear here"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyFragmentInterface {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentA fragmentA=new FragmentA();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.linear1,fragmentA);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    FragmentB fragmentB=new FragmentB();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager1=getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction  fragmentTransaction1=fragmentManager1.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction1.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction1.replace(R.id.linear2,fragmentB);
    fragmentTransaction1.commit();
}

@Override
public void setResult(String result) {
    FragmentB fragmentnew=new FragmentB();
    fragmentnew= (FragmentB) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.linear2);
    fragmentnew.putresult(result);
}
}
```

MyFragmentInterface.java

```
public interface MyFragmentInterface {
public void setResult(String result);

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="queendevelopers.com.communicate.MainActivity"
android:weightSum="2"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/linear1"
    android:orientation="vertical" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/linear2"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

error log:

```
 08-16 16:11:42.307 7630-7630/queendevelopers.com.communicate E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: queendevelopers.com.communicate, PID: 7630
                                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void queendevelopers.com.communicate.MyFragmentInterface.setResult(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at queendevelopers.com.communicate.FragmentA$1.onClick(FragmentA.java:34)
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4832)
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19844)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

Comment: Ok try it as `listener= (getActivity()) context;`

Comment: In Fragment B Java you are using `getActivity()` to get a reference to your text view, you need the Fragment view, do it like you have for Fragment A I.e. rootView.findByViewId ...

Comment: Thank you @MarkKeen  you solved my problem. Thank you again!! ;) it's  working great. the problem is  with the getActivity() but it would be best if u expand  this answer why the  getActivity() counter a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on the comment I made that solved the problem:

The original issue was not to do with your interface callback (this was not the root cause of the `NullPointerException`).

When the callback method `setResult(String result)` was invoked this line :
`fragmentnew.putresult(result);` was causing the null pointer because, in the method `putresult` in your fragment there is a null reference to your textView (`textView.setText(r);`).

For every `Activity` you can have an associated view heirarchy (your XML file), this is set by `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`.  Now if you try and reference any `@+id` widgets from the XML layout you can cast relevant object type : `TextView`, `EditText`, `ListView`.  Fragments (which are attached to a hosting Activity) can also have their own layouts,  this is inflated in `onCreateView()`. Your final code should look something like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b,container,false);
    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
    return view;
}
```

Your `view` object now contains your view hierarchy for the inflated XML Layout, from which you can access all widgets.

The line of code that was incorrect was:

`textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textview);`

The reason being you are using the convenience method `getActivity()` this will return the hosting `Activity` reference - thus you now will have access to the hosting `Activity` - used a lot for gaining a `Context` of other purposes, however your view id reference is invalid because it is in the view hierarchy of your inflated layout in your fragment.

Comment: Thanks Mark.. This answer made me clear about view and getActivity() method.

Answer (score 0):

Change in Fragment A:

**from**:

```
buton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int num1=Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
        int num2=Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());
        int result=num1+num2;
        listener.setResult(result+" ");
    }
});
```

**To**

```
buton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int num1=Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
        int num2=Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());
        int result=num1+num2;
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setResult(result+" ");
    }
});
```

Because I think your `listener` object is not initialised before being used so try this answer please.

Comment: himanshu getting same output!! Not working!! getActivity() and context is the same thing isn't it? Does any difference between them?

Comment: But in this case your activity is implementing the interface so its better to fetch the activity. Try my updated answer.

Comment: Bro, I have already tried, its not working.. getting the same result. I have posted all code you can test in your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method inside your Fragment

```
 @Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    listener = (MyFragmentInterface) getActivity();
}
```

Comment: so try this code in onActivityCreated(), on which version of Android are you testing ?

Comment: I am using Android Studio 2.2 Preview 6, No it's not  working on onActivityCreated too..

Answer (score 0):

try this 
(((MyFragmentInterface)getActivity()).setResult(result+" ");

Comment: may be super should before init listener.

Comment: before or after, no mater the error  is still on. Rid of this error.